# kenodui grid WebApi CRUD

Tags: asp.net-mvc, grid, kendo-ui

On the KendoUI site, I've found a working example of a KendoUI grid with MVC wrappers.
I don't use those wrappers.

Is there already support for json(p) for WebApi?

I've tried with the JsonPMediaTypeFormatter, with no decent result.
I can only read for the ApiController, but the put, post and delete don't work.

any examples?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do POST over JSONP.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an example on github.com site look at this :

https://github.com/telerik/kendo-examples-asp-net/

or

https://github.com/telerik/kendo-examples-asp-net/tree/master/grid-webapi-crud

this is web api and you can download it az zip file then add web-api assembly to it, it works with web-api very nice.

you can search about what exactly you need on this :

https://github.com/telerik/kendo-examples-asp-net/commit/b6d70769fc226340e16a7fdb6da4329331f7927b